# Use a 'join-query' like SQLAlchemy in Django?

Tags: django

How to use in Django： get user followed_set all articles?

use in sqlAlchemy：

```
Article.query.join(Follow, Follow.followed_id == Article.user_id)\
                .filter(Follow.follower_id == self.id)
```

My Code：

```
class User(AbstractUser):  # Author
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Follow(models.Model):  # user ManyToMany
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='followed_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='follower_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way can get all the followed of the user.

```
followed =  Follow.objects.filter(followed=user).values('followed')
articles = Article.objects.filter(user__in=followed)
```